# What is the complete list of all "Starship Troopers" comics?

Tags: comics, robert-a-heinlein, starship-troopers

[Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starship_Troopers#Comics) states:

> Comics
>   Dark Horse Comics, Mongoose Publishing and Markosia have held the license to produce comic books based on Starship Troopers. Over the years they have been written by writers like Warren Ellis, Gordon Rennie and Tony Lee.

However, I was not able to find the lists of every house which published Starship Troopers comics (I don't know if Wiki list above is complete), and wasn't very successful at finding a list of all comics for those three.

I found [this page](http://www.cydethan.com/index.php?page=starship-troopers) from Cy Dethan who writes for Markosia, and [this page](http://www.comics-db.com/pages/Dark_Horse_Comics/S/Starship_Troopers/) from Comics-DB listing some Dark Horse ones.

Comixology's "Starship Troopers" [search resulted in 6 hits](http://www.comixology.com/search?search=starship%20troopers) - all of them irrelevant (all 6 "Doctor Who" comics).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### **[Dark Horse Comics](http://starshiptroopers.wikia.com/wiki/Dark_Horse_Comics):**

- **Starship Troopers: Insect Touch (May, 1997)**

  - *Insect Touch issue 1*
  - *Insect Touch issue 2*
  - *Insect Touch issue 3*
- **Starship Troopers: Brute Creations (Sep, 1997)**
- **Starship Troopers: The Official Movie Adaptation (Oct, 1997)**

  - *Starship Troopers issue 1*
  - *Starship Troopers issue 2*
- **Starship Troopers: Flashback (Dark Horse presents #126 - Nov, 1997)**
- **Starship Troopers: Dominant Species (Aug, 1998)**

  - *Dominant Species issue 1*
  - *Dominant Species issue 2*
  - *Dominant Species issue 3*
  - *Dominant Species issue 4*

### **[Mongoose Publishing / Markosia](http://www.alibris.com/search/books/isbn/9781904854531)**

- **Starship Troopers : Blaze of Glory (Alamo Bay)**

  - *Blaze of Glory : Issue 1*
  - *Blaze of Glory : Issue 2*
  - *Blaze of Glory : Issue 3*
  - *Blaze of Glory : Issue 4*

### **[Markosia Publishing](http://www.markosia.com/titles/)**

- **Starship Troopers: Dead Man's Hand**

  - *Dead Man's Hand issue 1*
  - *Dead Man's Hand issue 2*
  - *Dead Man's Hand issue 3*
  - *Dead Man's Hand issue 4*
- **Starship Troopers: Damaged Justice (Nov, 2006)**

  - *Damaged Justice issue 1*
  - *Damaged Justice issue 2*
  - *Damaged Justice issue 3*
  - *Damaged Justice issue 4*
- **Starship Troopers (Markosia)**
- **Starship Troopers issue 0**
- **Starship Troopers: Marooned**

  - *Marooned issue 1*
  - *Marooned issue 2*
  - *Marooned issue 3*
  - *Marooned issue 4*
- **Starship Troopers: Bad Blood**

  - *Bad Blood issue 1*
  - *Bad Blood issue 2*
  - *Bad Blood issue 3*
  - *Bad Blood issue 4*
- **Starship Troopers: Triple Threat**

  - *Triple Threat issue 1*
  - *Triple Threat issue 2*
- **War Stories: Tasch**
- **Starship Troopers : Fool's Errand**

  - *Fool's Errand issue 1*
  - *Fool's Errand issue 2*
  - *Fool's Errand issue 3*
  - *Fool's Errand issue 4*
- **Starship Troopers : War Stories**

  - *Vandal's One Shots*

Comment: Wow! Amazing! I am kinda curious what your sources were, but +1 and accept

Comment: I just hunted around. I'm not certain that the list's completely exhaustive though as there seem to be a few odd "one shots" that got licensed in the run-up to the sequels

Answer (score 2):

- Insect touch #1, Dark Horse, UPC 7-61568-96742-5 00111 (May, 1997)
- Insect touch #2, Dark Horse, UPC 7-61568-96742-5 00211
- Insect touch #3, Dark Horse, UPC 7-61568-96742-5 00311
- Brute creations, Dark Horse, UPC 7-61568-97202-3 00111 (Sep, 1997)
- The official movie adaptation #1, Dark Horse, UPC 7-61568-96792-0 00111 (Oct, 1997)
- The official movie adaptation #2, Dark Horse, UPC 7-61568-96792-0 00211
- Dark horse presents #126 - Flashback, Dark Horse, UPC 7-61568-94852-3 12611
  (Nov, 1997)
- Dominant species #1, Dark Horse, UPC 7-61568-97374-7 00111 (Aug, 1998)
- Dominant species #2, Dark Horse, UPC 7-61568-97374-7 00211 (Sep, 1998)
- Dominant species #3, Dark Horse, UPC 7-61568-97374-7 00311 (Oct, 1998)
- Dominant species #4, Dark Horse, UPC 7-61568-97374-7 00411 (Nov, 1998)
- Blaze of glory #1, Markosia, UPC 9-77175-01547-7 01,
  ISSN 1750-1547-01 (Mar, 2006)
- Blaze of glory #2, Markosia, UPC 9-77175-01547-7 02,
  ISSN 1750-1547-02 (Apr, 2006)
- Blaze of glory #3, Markosia, UPC 9-77175-01547-7 03,
  ISSN 1750-1547-03 (May, 2006)
- Blaze of glory #4, Markosia, UPC 9-77175-01547-7 04,
  ISSN 1750-1547-04 (Jun, 2006)
- Dead man’s hand #1, Markosia, UPC 9-77175-01547-7 21,
  ISSN 1750-1547-21 (Jul, 2006)
- Dead man’s hand #2, Markosia, UPC 9-77175-01547-7 22,
  ISSN 1750-1547-22 (Aug, 2006)
- Dead man’s hand #3, Markosia, UPC 9-77175-01547-7 23,
  ISSN 1750-1547-23 (Sep, 2006)
- Dead man’s hand #4, Markosia, UPC 9-77175-01547-7 24,
  ISSN 1750-1547-24 (Oct, 2006)
- Damaged justice #1, Markosia, UPC 9-77175-01547-7 31 (Nov, 2006)
- Damaged justice #2, Markosia, UPC 9-77175-01547-7 32 (Feb, 2007)
- Damaged justice #3, Markosia, UPC 9-77175-01547-7 33 (Mar, 2007)
- Damaged justice #4, Markosia, UPC 9-77175-01547-7 34 (Apr, 2007)
- Zero #0 – A tiger’s tale  – Previews exclusive, Markosia, UPC 9-77175-01547-7 00 (Oct/Nov, 06)
- (01) Marooned #1, Markosia, UPC 9-77175-33767-8 01 (Apr, 2007)
- (02) Marooned #2, Markosia, UPC 9-77175-33767-8 02 (May, 2007)
- (03) Marooned #3, Markosia, UPC 9-77175-33767-8 03 (Jul, 2007)
- (04) Marooned #4, Markosia, UPC 9-77175-33767-8 04 (Jul, 2007)
- (05) Bad blood #1, Markosia, UPC 5-060116-710113 05 (Jan, 2008)
- (06) Bad blood #2, Markosia, UPC 5-060116-710199 06 (Feb, 2008)
- (07) Bad blood #3, Markosia, UPC 5-060116-710045 07 (Mar, 2008)
- (08) Bad blood #4, Markosia, UPC 5-060116-710137 08 (Apr, 2008)
- (09) Triple threat #1, Markosia, UPC 5-060116-710304 09 (Jul, 2008)
- (10) Triple threat #2, Markosia, UPC 5-060116-710366 10 (Aug, 2008)
- (11) War stories: Tasch

**Do note that:**

1. Never released: Fool's Errand #1-#4, which would have been (12-15)
2. There are also TPB's (=Trade Paper backs, sort of bundles)
3. Also I'm still in the process of figuring out, which issues of "signs and portents" from Mongoose contain short comics on the SST universe.
4. I left out the Novel (which most people know exists), the adventure book (which most people dont know exists), any of the boardgames (incl. RPG and table top which are 2 separate things), and any of the software games.
5. I've also left out any information on amount of cover variants. The sources online are not reliable: I own some cover variants which are not properly documented in some of the comic databases. And therefore I'm not sure how many variants there are per issue.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.   This appears to be the same list previously posted by Valorum.  What are you adding that's new?

Comment: As you can see I've also corrected/updated Valorums post in the past. My post contains the UPC and ISSN numbers. I will also be updating it with extra info (see the bottom). Additionally, the numbering of the last 11 issues, which is confusing for first time collectors.