# Were there any "Starship Troopers" comics closer to the spirit of the book than the movie?

Tags: comics, robert-a-heinlein, starship-troopers

I know there there were [several different publishers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13719/what-is-the-complete-list-of-all-starship-troopers-comics) that put out "Starship Troopers" comics.

Some of those comics seem to be full movie tie-ins (2 were actual "comicalization" of the movie).

Since the movie and the book were so [diametrally](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13666/in-the-starship-troopers-movie-what-remains-of-robert-a-heinleins-original-no) different, I was wondering if any of the comics were more based on the book than on the movie? (Mostly, philosophically/message wise, less so in plot details). Or were they all 100% tied to the movie and not the book?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I'd like to know more.

Comment: @MajorStackings - that comment was NOT based on the book :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Referring to my answer [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13719/what-is-the-complete-list-of-all-starship-troopers-comics), the short answer is that **all** of the Starship Trooper comics are based on the events of the Theatrical movies and generally mirror the events within. There are **no** comics (as far as I'm aware) that were solely tied to the books.

In addition to the film and the comic series, it's worth noting that there was also an [OVA anime series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starship_Troopers_%28OVA%29) produced in 1988 which had a (slightly) closer match to the original books, albeit with a much heavier emphasis on the warfare elements (e.g. mecha-soldiers) and substantially less focus on the politics than even the films.

[image: Starship Troopers OVA]

Even the very earliest tie-ins (including a 1976 board game entitled "[Starship Troopers : The Board Game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starship_Troopers_%28board_wargame%29)" and 1982 Tandy Computer Game entitled "[Klendathu](http://www.mobygames.com/game/trs-80-coco/klendathu)") focus almost exclusively on the *martial* aspects of the book rather than the deeper socio-political discussions contained within;

[image: Starship Troopers 1976 Board Game]

[image: Klendathu Tandy Game]